# HTTP4S EntityEncoder

Tags: scala, zio, http4s, http4s-circe

I have created HttpRoutes for ZIO app

```
class BlockChainAPI[R <: BlockChain] {
  type BlockChainTask[A] = RIO[R, A]
  private val dsl = Http4sDsl[BlockChainTask]

  import dsl._

  implicit def jsonDecoder[A](implicit decoder: Decoder[A]): EntityDecoder[BlockChainTask, A] = jsonOf[BlockChainTask, A]

  implicit def jsonEncoder[A](implicit encoder: Encoder[A]): EntityEncoder[BlockChainTask, A] = jsonEncoderOf[BlockChainTask, A]

  val routes: HttpRoutes[BlockChainTask] = HttpRoutes.of[BlockChainTask] {

    case GET -> Root / "message" / message =>
      val newMessage = BlockMessage(message)
      BlockChain
        .addBlock(Seq(newMessage))
        .foldZIO(
          err => BadRequest(err.getMessage),
          _ => Ok(s"Message $message added")
        )
  }
}
```

and it works fine! But today I've added a new route:

```
    case GET -> Root =>
      StaticFile.fromPath(fs2.io.file.Path("/api-docs/index.html")).getOrElse(NotFound()).foldZIO(
        err => InternalServerError(err.getMessage),
        result => Ok(result)
      )
```

and it fails with error:
Cannot convert from Product with java.io.Serializable to an Entity, because no EntityEncoder[[A]zio.ZIO[R,Throwable,A], Product with java.io.Serializable] instance could be found.

Maybe someone knows how to fix it?!

I added:

```
implicit def jsonEncoder2[A <: Product with Serializable](implicit encoder: Encoder[A]): EntityEncoder[BlockChainTask, A] = jsonEncoderOf[BlockChainTask, A]
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `result` has a `Product with Serializable` type, which is not something http4s knows how to encode it in the HTTP response.

This is because `StaticFile.fromPath(fs2.io.file.Path("/api-docs/index.html")).getOrElse(NotFound())` actually gives you 2 unrelated types depending on whether you go through the nominal path or the `getOrElse` path.

You need to return a consistent type in both paths, or don't use `getOrElse` at this stage, or move the missing case to the error channel.

Using intermediate variables with explicit types should help you.

Comment: I've changed getOrElse to getOrElseF(throw new Throwable()) and now I have this
`Cannot convert from org.http4s.Response[[β$1$]zio.ZIO[Nothing,Throwable,β$1$]] to an Entity, because no EntityEncoder[[A]zio.ZIO[R,Throwable,A], org.http4s.Response[[β$1$]zio.ZIO[Nothing,Throwable,β$1$]]] instance could be found.`

Comment: What is the type of `StaticFile.fromPath`?

Comment: OptionT[F, Response[F]]

Comment: I found work approach:
StaticFile.fromResource("index.html", Some(req)).getOrElseF(NotFound())